# Lazy load image doesn't appear in tabs until scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know that there are many topic about this issue but I did not found a solution to fix it. 
I have a dropdown menu with tabs and when the tab which contain a image is active, the image doesn't appear until I scroll.

I tried some of these but it's still not working :

```
$("img.lazy").show().lazyload()
   $(window).resize()
```

---

```
 $(function() {
            $("img.lazy").show().lazyload()
            window.onload = function() {
                $(window).resize()
            };


});
```

## [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zkbqLxqv/4/)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If there's not a lot of images in there, you could maybe don't use the lazyload on them.

Comment: I'll add more tabs and more images, the fiddle is just for the exemple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [lazySizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/). This lazyloader detects any visibility changes automatically for current and future img elements and also runs a lot faster than the old jquery lazyload.

Simply add the lazysizes script and add the class `lazyload` and use the `data-src` instead of the normal `src` attribute.

In case you want to leave the class `lazy` and the `data-original` markup, you can also configure lazysizes to take those:

```
window.lazySizesConfig = window.lazySizesConfig || {};

// use .lazy instead of .lazyload
window.lazySizesConfig.lazyClass = 'lazy';

// use data-original instead of data-src
lazySizesConfig.srcAttr = 'data-original';
```

Here is a working [example of fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eb4osdh7/7/).

---

You really shouldn't trigger a general resize event (on load). A lot of widgets do listen for this event and will do a re-layout in case a resize happens (== really bad for performance).

Answer (score 2):

Documentation: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

States you can trigger via event.

I changed the classes of these to images to `lazymenu` (in case you have other lazy images).

Then, added this line to your top `#nav .dropdown_trigger`:

`$('img.lazymenu').trigger('click');`

Then, updated you lazy call to:

`$("img.lazymenu").show().lazyload({ event : 'click' });`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zkbqLxqv/10/

Comment: That's works thanks you very much :)
Can I ask you somethings else, is it possible to only load the image which is contained in tab ? I mean when we hovering the tab 1, load and show images from tab 1, but do not load the other until we have not hovered the tab2, tab3...
Thanks you for your time I appreciate very much

Comment: Yes, you could do that (load individual images). It's not as easy as the solution I provided because you'd have to hook up each image. I'll see if I can work out a fiddle.

Comment: Thanks you, I'm looking forward for your feed back :)

Comment: Eh, that wasn't so bad, actually. https://jsfiddle.net/4b1evsfa/1/ Notice that I'm loading the first image on your main MENU hover because it is shown by default.